# JRuby環境のみ、katanaka hiragana へのパターンマッチが RegexpError となる

Tags: ruby

日本語 Windows上で、ruby で動作中のシステムを jruby に移植しようとしてます。
その作業中に気づいたのですが、crubyでは再現しない、jruby のエラーがありました。

```
str = "あいうえお"
str.sub!(/(\p{katakana}|\p{hiragana})/, "xx")
```

こちらのコードですが、ソースコードを utf8 で保存した場合は
問題なく実行できるのですが、cp932 で保存すると RegexpError となってしまいます。

```
SyntaxError: d:\tmp\r.rb:6: (RegexpError) invalid character property name <kata>: /(\p{katakana}|\p{hiragana})/
str.sub!(/(\p{katakana}|\p{hiragana})/, "xx")
                                     ^
```

jrubyに固有の問題なのか、切り分けがつかなかったので、アドバイスなど頂けると嬉しいです。

jruby 9.2.8.0 (2.5.3) 2019-08-12 a1ac7ff OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.4+11 on 11.0.4+11 +jit [mswin32-x86_64]